# strange characters in wordpress website displayed for visitors

Tags: errors, plugin-w3-total-cache, characters, compression

Apparently a lot of people complain that they only see random letters and characters:

[image]

My biggest problem is that I can't reproduce the problem on ANY of my devices!
Not on my Windows XP laptop, not on my Windows 7 laptop, not on my Android phone or my iPod Touch. It doesn't matter which browser I'm using.
The only time I see the problem myself is when I try to share one of my blog posts on Google+, because the blog description then appears in strange characters.

So, **first of all** I need to find a way to reproduce the problem somehow.
Otherwise I won't be able to see if what I did fixed the problem or not.

I did everything that @toscho recommended, but nothing helped.

Did anybody ever run into a similar problem or would you know where I could start to look for the problem?

Edit: I contacted my webhost. They couldn't reproduce the problem, just like me.
They said that they have enabled gzip compression on their servers. They suggested turning off one plugin after another to see what happens, but as I can't reproduce the problem, I can't do that. Please help!

More and more readers are complaining about this problem. Most of them just need to refresh the page or wait a few minutes and then the site loads normally, but I'm still using a lot of traffic because of that.

EDIT 2: The W3 Total Cache Plugin FAQ says:
**I see garbage characters instead of the normal web site, what's going on here?**

If a theme or it's files use the call php_flush() or function flush() that will interfere with the plugins normal operation; making the plugin send cached files before essential operations have finished. The flush() call is no longer necessary and should be removed.

I am pretty sure that none of my code has this call anywhere, but I'm not 100% sure.
Is there any way to find out other than searching through millions of characters in all of my files?

Comment: Ignore the markup, that’s only relevant when the page is saved to the local file system or when the server doesn’t send the correct HTTP header. An URL to a page where this happens could help.

Comment: You send the content gzip encoded but the gzip file is invalid. Turn off gzip compression and add the details to your question about how you turned it **on**.

Comment: Hm, looks like it is gzip encoded twice. See [this discussion](http://drupal.org/node/1440534) for something similar.

Comment: I use a plugin called "W3 Total Cache". Within this plugin I turned off the following option: "Enable HTTP (gzip) compression ". Could you see if the problem you mentioned still persists? Thank you.

Comment: It works now as expected. I’ll write an answer with more details …

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let’s start with the output we got before the fix:

[image]

What happened here? My **guess:** a collision between the [plugin W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/) and your web server [LiteSpeed](http://www.litespeedtech.com/docs/webserver/config/tuning/#enableGzipCompress). I found a [thread in a Drupal forum](http://drupal.org/node/1440534) about a very similar (or the same) issue.

LiteSpeed seems not to send the appropriate HTTP headers for the compressed cache files W3TC stores. In [its changelog](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/changelog/) for version **0.9.2.4** W3TC says:

> Fixed LiteSpeed web server support

So the issue seems to be known, and an upgrade should fix it.

If the upgrade did not help …

- Ask your web hoster. You pay for support, and nobody knows the internals better.
- Or add …

  ```
  AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
  AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
  ```

  … to your .htaccess to see if it helps.
- Or turn gzip compression off in W3TC. That is the last option if all the other approaches fail.

To test the results, do not rely on browser output. All browsers use different workarounds for broken compression, you cannot work with that. Use a tool like [GIDZipTest](http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php) to see if everything is okay.

Comment: Thank you very much. My plugins are always up to date and I just checked. I'm already using the newest upgrade 0.9.2.4 - obviously that alone doesn't fix the problem. I take the other steps you suggested and will check with the tool you recommended. I hope I can fix the problem with that. Thank you!

Comment: Where would I put the code snippet in my .htaccess file to make it work? I just put it at the very end, but it didn't have any effect. Here's what my .htaccess file looks like right now: http://pastebin.com/j0qDqBUV

Comment: Should not matter. Try something else: Remove the line `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE …`

Comment: I did. Thanks. I'm not sure if it fixed the problem. The DIDZipTest works, but in IE I still see strange letters.

Comment: Maybe a local caching issue in IE? After deleting the browser cache I got a working site.

Comment: Looks like it fixed the issue then, because now I get the site to load properly as well. Thanks so much!

Comment: Ran into this problem this morning.  Thanks for the help! +1

Comment: The problem seems to persist: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67773/feedburner-doesnt-work-anymore
I can't reconstruct the problem myself, though.
Any other ideas what I could do?

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me because I had two plugins trying to GZip compress the output.  Disabling the second plugin fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Always specify the encoding used for an HTML or XML page. If you don't, characters in your content may be incorrectly interpreted. Look inside your header file to specify English and UTF-8 settings. Here's whats in my header:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: Aliyah thank you! I thought I had it specified already (see my edited question for the code snippet), though it does call for some action, maybe it would be better to replace it with what you are using instead? I think I originally changed it because I also need to display Japanese characters as well as English and German.

Comment: And by the way, @toscho is the expert here. I have no idea what Im talking about lol. Not to the extent that Im sure tosho does.

Comment: @japanworm, I visited your site and I dont see anything weird going on there. Its very cute. :)

Comment: Thank you! I checked again and saw that the snippet in my header has already been in my parent theme, but that doesn't mean it's without any faults. I hope "toscho" has a good idea. If not, I'll try what you suggested and see what happens. And thanks very much for the nice compliment! :)

Comment: @japan, we have a big problemo. I just went back to your site in 2 different browsers and all I see is a page full of funny characters. Your site doesnt even show up. Its not a browser issue. There must be some code messing up your site. Not sure if it has an effect or not but did you copy and paste my header into yours, replacing what yours had, all of it? In the meantime, Ill look into it and report back shortly

Comment: Are you using a cache plugin? I'm looking at a cache plugin as the primary suspect. My suspicions could be wrong (i dont use cache plugins) but they've caused problems in the past as simple as css issues showing up properly.

Comment: Yeah, that is a big problem indeed! :( That's why I want to figure out how to fix it ASAP! Thanks so much! I haven't changed anything at all. Yes, I'm using a cache plugin. I turn it off now, can you check if the problem persists?

Comment: @japanworm - its too early to tell if the problem is gone for good because first, your site worked fine and then suddenly, it didnt and then it did again. So to  monitor this, you'll need to keep the plugin off for a while to see it the issue ever reoccurs. In the meantime, site is showing up fine once again. I'd also recommend you following up with tosho. He's a pro.

Comment: I just came back and read over some of my comments where I said toscho is a pro, then I looked at how much rep/points he has and had to laugh at the thought of me never getting that many lol. Anyway im glad its working for ya! Your site is super cute :-D