# Weird Symbols in Chrome (wordpress)

Tags: homepage

I was changing a few lines of php and jquery code and this happened in my wordpress website:
[Image](http://www.millionshomepages.com/weird.png)

The weirdest part is that i changed everything back and this still happens and also if you view the website in firefox it will be perfecly fine.

I have no idea what is wrong. I did not install any new plugins.

Comment: Disable gzip, see [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59309/page-output-in-strange-characters-uncompressed-gzip/59332#59332) for details. Does it still happen?

Comment: Can you use [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or similar to see what's happening on the network?

Comment: I added that part on the .htacess and deleted every cache plugin including w3c total cache and it still happens

Comment: @user1555009 did you delete your browser cache (of everything) this will get rid of the garbage cached files on your local computer

Comment: Tried that too and tried opening the website in another computer and it didin't work :s

Comment: Maybe Chrome character set is wrong,